# Show a different image everytime the button is clicked

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a button that will display a different image ever time it gets clicked in C# by integer increment

**C#**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  int a = 0;

    a++;

    if (a == 1)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://s20.postimg.org/uazs6u2p9/99639488.png";
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "http://s20.postimg.org/cdopdvz8t/99639514.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `int a = 0` so it is outside the click method.  As it stands, everytime you click, a = 1;

Comment: put the a initialization outside of the click method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `int a` inside method so every time you click button a new int with value of 0 is created. and you always increment 0 to 1.

Instead declare `int a` as a field. also put a default condition to reset the counter when it reaches the maximum available cases.

```
private int a = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a++;

    switch(a)
    { 
        case 1: pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://s20.postimg.org/uazs6u2p9/99639488.png";
                break;
        case 2: pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "http://s20.postimg.org/cdopdvz8t/99639514.png";
                break;

        // put more cases here

        default: a = 0; // reset counter
                 break;
    }
}
```

There is also another way, instead of using `int` and display images in sequence you can use random int and randomize images.

```
private Random r = new Random();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(r.Next(1,2))
    { 
        case 1: pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "http://s20.postimg.org/uazs6u2p9/99639488.png";
                break;
        case 2: pictureBox2.ImageLocation = "http://s20.postimg.org/cdopdvz8t/99639514.png";
                break;

        // put more cases here
    }
}
```

`r.Next(x,y)` simply produces a random number between x and y. so if you have 10 cases you must do `r.Next(1,10)`. if you have 6 cases do `r.Next(1,6)` etc...